# Android bluetooth, получение имен устройств

Tags: java, android, json, bluetooth

Как из массива `discoveredDevices` достать названия устройств,  а не MAC-адреса?

Код:

```
 public void discoverDevices(View view) {

    discoveredDevices.clear();
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if (discoverDevicesReceiver == null) {
        discoverDevicesReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    if (!discoveredDevices.contains(device)) {
                        discoveredDevices.add(device);
                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
     //some 

final JSONArray Codes = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(discoveredDevices));
//Codes result = mac адреса, мне нужны названия
```

Comment: покажите код что вы пробовали

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev добавил код в вопрос

Comment: @IlyaNenilin то есть вопрос сводится к получению названий Bluetooth устройств, а не к получению списка и формированию JSON?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов можно и так сказать, но данный код не дает нужного мне результата

Comment: @IlyaNenilin Тогда рекомендую переформулировать и отредактировать вопрос чтобы было понятно в чем же именно проблема.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов что собственно не понятно? Хорошо переформулирую вопрос

Comment: @IlyaNenilin непонятно в чем именно проблема: в поиске BT-устройств, в получении их списка, в формировании JSON или все же в получении ИМЕНИ устройства?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов так понятнее вопрос стал?

Comment: @IlyaNenilin отож! Я еще немного поменял заголовок и поставил вопрос о его открытии заново.

Comment: у класса BluetoothDevice  есть метод, который отдает его имя. Как вы думаете, как этот метод называется?

Comment: @metalurgus getName () я знаю,  у меня и не получается с ним работать.  Получилось бы не спрашивал бы

Comment: @metalurgus вопрос дан,  ответа нет. У меня не получается из за не хватки опыта. Я и прошу пример кода у опытных.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
   s.add(bt.getName());
```